# Multistep Multivariate Time Series Classification in Keras

Tags: keras, time, deep-learning, classification, series

I wonder if you could help me , I have a 3 class time series classification problem, for which I need to predict the class up to two steps in the future.
I have coded the output with one hot encoder so I have 3 columns
I have doubts on the dimension of the output layer.  When I worked with just one step to the future I could use

"model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))"

and the the code I have worked ok, but I am not sure what output layer to use instead when I have 2 steps.

The dimensions of my training data are as follows:

ytrain2
(100861, 2, 3)
xtrain2
(100861, 6, 9)

---

```
from numpy import array
print(xnorm.shape)
Xtrain2, ytrain2 = split_sequence(xnorm,ynorm,6,2)
print(ytrain2)
Xtestf, ytestf = split_sequence(xtestnorm,ytestnorm,6,2)
print(ytrain2.shape)
recallV=list()
misclasV=list()
for i in n:
  for j in neurons:
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dropout
    import tensorflow as tf
    import keras as ks
    n_input = Xtrain2.shape[1] * Xtrain2.shape[2]
    ny=ytrain2.shape[1] * ytrain2.shape[2]
    X = Xtrain2.reshape(Xtrain2.shape[0],n_input)
    ytrain3=ytrain2.reshape(ytrain2.shape[0], ny)
    optimizer = ks.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
    from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
    from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
    callbackEarlyStop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)

    reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.95,
                              patience=5, min_lr=0.0000001,verbose=1)
    # define model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(j, activation='relu', input_dim=n_input))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(j, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    ###problem is here##
    model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))**
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X, ytrain3,epochs=100,batch_size=256,shuffle=False,validation_split=0.2,callbacks=[reduce_lr,callbackEarlyStop], verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I figured out the answer, the problem just gets solved by using Keras functional API and doing a multioutput neural network, an extract of the code is :

```
 y1 = ytrain2[:, 0].reshape((ytrain2.shape[0], ytrain2.shape[1]))
 y2 = ytrain2[:, 1].reshape((ytrain2.shape[0], ytrain2.shape[1]))
 y3 = ytrain2[:, 2].reshape((ytrain2.shape[0],ytrain2.shape[1]))
 
 Input_1= Input(shape=(n_input,))

 x = Dense(120, activation='relu')(Input_1)
 x=  Dropout(0.15)(x)
 x = Dense(120, activation='relu')(x)
 x=  Dropout(0.15)(x)
 x = Dense(120, activation='relu')(x)
 x=  Dropout(0.15)(x)

 out1 = Dense(3,activation='softmax')(x)
 out2 = Dense(3,activation='softmax')(x)
 out3 = Dense(3,activation='softmax')(x)
 model = Model(inputs=Input_1, outputs=[out1, out2, out3])
 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=rec)
 model.fit(X, [y1,y2,y3],epochs=1054,batch_size=1024,shuffle=True,validation_split=0.12,callbacks=[reduce_lr,callbackEarlyStop], verbose=2
```